# "Error found when loading /etc/profile:" after upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, login

Recently, I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10. Now, each time I boot my machine I face an error message which reads as following:

`"Error found when loading /etc/profile:`

`find: '/usr/lib/wims/bin': Permission denied`
`find: '/usr/lib/wims/bin': Permission denied`
`find: '/usr/lib/wims/bin': Permission denied`
`find: '/usr/lib/wims/bin': Permission denied`
`find: '/usr/lib/wims/bin': Permission denied`
`find: '/usr/lib/wims/bin': Permission denied`
`find: '/usr/lib/wims/bin': Permission denied`
`find: '/usr/lib/wims/bin': Permission denied`
`find: '/usr/lib/wims/bin': Permission denied`
`find: '/usr/lib/wims/bin': Permission denied`

`As a result the session will not be configured correctly. You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.`

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

**Updated:**
The output of `ls -ld /usr/lib/wims/bin` is
`drwx------ 2 wims wims 4096 Feb 24  2018 /usr/lib/wims/bin`

Comment: what are the permissions of `/usr/lib/wims/bin`?

Comment: @Debian_yadav, how to find that out?

Comment: what is the output of `ls -ld /usr/lib/wims/bin`

Comment: @Debian_yadav,... updated the question...output is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too, but with a different file. When I checked the permission of the file with `ls -l` it showed that root was able to execute, read, and write, but the group and others not. So what fixed the problem to me was to change the permission of the file with:

```
$ chmod +756 /path/to/your/file
```

It will give permission to read, write and execute to root, read and execute to group, and read and write to others. It solved my problem.

Comment: Meanwhile I switched to Lubuntu. I don't know if I should accept the answer. :)

Comment: Leave it as it is now, if it helps someone else they will up vote it and everything will be fine.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me!